# How do I change the user agent in my WebView using Swift 4.2?

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, user-agent

I'm struggling with changing the user agent on my project using the latest Xcode version with swift 4.2 .

I want to pretend that I'm a Mac visiting a specific website.
Please edit this code and post it in the comments

Here's my code so far.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36 Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10"
        let myURL = NSURL(string: "http://website.com")
        let myURLRequest:NSURLRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL! as URL) as NSURLRequest
        webview.load(myURLRequest as URLRequest)
        myURLRequest.setValue(userAgent, forKey: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2227.1 Safari/537.36")

        webview.load(URLRequest(url: myURL! as URL))
    }
}
```

If I build it I receive this error:

![Error][2].

Comment: You are not showing us the important part of the error message. In the console, scroll up to the top of the stack trace. There you will see a full error message. Copy and paste the full error message into your question (as text).

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that you really should update your question with the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem i seeing here, first time loading without the `user-agent` set and then setting it wrongly and put another request

Please check the [appledoc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutableurlrequest/1408793-setvalue), for setting up the HTTPHeaderField.

Based on your given code, the solution would be

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.116 Safari/537.36 Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B334b Safari/531.21.10"
        if let myURL = URL(string: "http://website.com") {
            var myURLRequest= URLRequest(url: myURL)
            myURLRequest.setValue(userAgent, forHTTPHeaderField:"user-agent")
            webview.load(myURLRequest)
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Ratul Sharker, 
Thanks for your quick response.But unfortunately Xcode gives me another error saying "Use of unresolved identifier 'forHTTPHeaderField' " in the line where the setValue function is being called.....
I've came across this kind of solution already...
Do you know the problem here?

Comment: i've updated my code, previously i called the `setValue` wrongly and also declare the `myURLRequest` as `let`, for mutating it should be `var`.

Comment: thank you for your help.
There's no error occurring anymore.
What user agent string should I put in "user-agent" if I want to visit the site as Mac OS 10.13.6 using Chrome? I found nothing there neither..

Comment: Using chrome's `inspect-element` it can be easily found. In the network tab it's look like `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; SM-G900P Build/LRX21T) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Mobile Safari/537.36`

Comment: Just change the current userAgent string to the given string constant.

Answer (score 8):

`WKWebView` has a property called [customUserAgent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1414950-customuseragent) exactly for this purpose:

```
let customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 ..." // Your custom user agent string goes here"
webView.customUserAgent = customUserAgent
```

Comment: Thank you!. you saved my life. I have read all the possible answer on stackoverflow but finally I got this.